# how to scatter two arrays in one message in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I'm doing a university homework in which there is a question to do matrix-vector multiplication using single-column strategy, basically every process gets a column of the matrix - let's call it `A` - , because of matrix-vector definition every process gets one element of the vector - let's call it `x` -, here is the function I have :

```
double *mpiSingleColumn(const double *A,const double *x,const int size,const int rank){
    double *col=calloc(size,sizeof(double)),xi=0.0,*cols=calloc(size,sizeof(double)),*y=NULL;
    MPI_Request request;
    MPI_Iscatter(x,1,MPI_DOUBLE,&xi,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
    MPI_Datatype vectype,resizedvectype;
    MPI_Type_vector(size,1,size,MPI_DOUBLE,&vectype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&vectype);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(vectype,0,sizeof(double),&resizedvectype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&resizedvectype);
    MPI_Scatter(A,1,resizedvectype,col,size,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Type_free(&vectype);
    MPI_Type_free(&resizedvectype);
    MPI_Wait(&request,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        cols[i]=xi*col[i];
    free(col);
    if(rank==0)
        y=calloc(size,sizeof(double));
    MPI_Reduce(cols,y,size,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    free(cols);
    return y;
}
```

`A` is the matrix, `x` is the vector, `size` is the dimension of `A` which equals the size of `x` which for this problem equals the number of processes, `rank` is the process's rank.

the function above works perfectly and produces the desired results. However, right now I'm scattering `x` and `A` in two messages and I'd like(if it's possible) to scatter them in one, Yes I'm aware that the first scatter is asynchronous but still it's a message.

I've thought of derived types , specifically `MPI_Type_create_struct` but that works when I have an array of structs which I don't .

I've also looked into `MPI_Scatterv` and it works with one array too, I've looked into `MPI_Pack` which seemed the closest to what I want but I don't know how to put it with `Scatter` , I know how to put it with `Send` though.

I'm aware of MPI-2 RMA and MPI-3 shared memory but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it in message-passing style.

So how to do this(if it's possible) ?

By the way to explain the function above every column gets multiplied by `x[i]` where `i` is the col-number then the resulting columns are summed, if you do the mathematics you'll realize that the result is indeed `A*x` :) .

Comment: as a side note, you do **not** need `MPI_Type_commit(&vectype);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You (or MPI) need to put each column of the matrix and associated value x into a continuous chunk of memory.
Whether you do this yourself or via MPI_Pack() doesn't really matter.
Below is an example of doing it manually, but its the same structure using MPI_Pack():

```
int i;
double * buf;
double * extendedCol;
if (rank == 0) {
  buf = malloc(sizeof(*buf)*(size+1));
  // this will need to change if you don't have 1 process per column
  for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    memcpy(buf+(i*(size+1)), A+(i*size),(size+1)*sizeof(*buf));
  }
}

extendedCol=malloc((size+1)*sizeof(*extendedCol));

MPI_Scatter(buf,1,resizedvectype,extendedCol,size+1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
  cols[i]=extendedCol[size]*extendedCol[i];
}
```

Note, many MPI programs are memory limited, so this kind of memory shuffling is generally not an option/good idea. However, since you're already storing all of A in a single process, we'll assume memory is not an issue (if it is you either need to read in data into an already interleaved datastructure, or live with the two messages).

Edit: Fix `col` -> `extendedCol`

Comment: guess then there is no way to scatter data from two memory locations, by the way `extendedCol` should be `col` I think

Comment: At some point during transport the memory has to be at a single location (otherwise it's not really a single message). There are many research papers out there proposing adding 'streaming' to MPI, which would come close to accomplishing what you want (but this isn't really 'message passing').

Comment: I don't like this answer. It wastes a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with `MPI_Type_create_struct`, but you need one that deals in absolute memory addresses: `MPI_Type_create_hindexed`.

However, considering that the `I` variants can overlap and pipeline and such, that's an efficient enough solution.